# Automatic Module cannot be found

Tags: java, java-module, module-info

I cannot import org.json as an Automatic Module.

I've set up a very simple test project with the following directory structure:

```
src\module-info.java
src\uk\co\stikman\broken\Example.java
lib\json-20200518.jar
```

**module-info**:

```
module uk.co.stikman.broken {
    requires json;
}
```

I try to run `javac` as:

```
javac --module-path lib -d output src\module-info.java src\uk\co\stikman\broken\Example.java
```

Which returns the error:

```
src\module-info.java:2: error: module not found: json
        requires json;
```

[org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20200518) is not a modular project, and it's my understanding that including it on the module-path would turn it into an "Automatic Module" with its name being derived from the filename `json-20200518.jar`

What am I doing wrong/not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
requires json;
```

to

```
requires org.json;
```

The reason for that is specified in the `META-INF` of the artifact.

```
Automatic-Module-Name: org.json
```

Comment: Aha, perfect answer.  I had not seen mention of `Automatic-Module-Name` in my travels, thanks.